# Why is the identity not loaded when resolving WebApi but is when resolving Mvc controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am using Autofac for an Inversion of Control container which is configured like this

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        configureIoC(app);
        configureAuth(app);
    }

    void configureIoC(IAppBuilder app) {
        var b = new ContainerBuilder();
        //...
        b.Register(c => HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity 
                    ?? new NullIdentity()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        var container = b.Build();
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

I believe the fact that this is Autofac versus some other container is probably irrelevant to what I'm seing. They key line here is the one configuring any dependency on `IIdentity` to be plucked from `HttpContext.Current`.

I use it like this so that I can have stub-able access to the current user anywhere I want.

```
public interface ICurrentUser {
    Task<AppUser> Get();
}
public class CurrentUserProvider : ICurrentUser {
    public async Task<AppUser> Get() => await users.FindByNameAsync(currentLogin.GetUserId());

    public CurrentUserProvider(AppUserManager users, IIdentity currentLogin) {
        this.users = users;
        this.currentLogin = currentLogin;
    }

}
```

I've used this pattern on past projects and it works fine. I'm currently applying it to an existing project and seeing a very strange thing.

- When an **Asp.net Mvc** controller depends on `ICurrentUser` everything works fine
- When a **WebApi** controller gets an instance of `ICurrentUser` the `Get` operation fails since the instance of `IIdentity` has not been parsed from the cookie and does not yet have Claims loaded into it (`AuthenticationType == null`)! Oddly, if I pause the debugger after the WebApi controller is instantiated I can hit `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` and see that `AuthenticationType == "Cookie"` and all claims are there.

What this leads me to conclude is that somehow things are happening in the following order

- If this is a web api route, the Web Api controller creates an instance
- Asp.Net Identity fills out the current `HttpContext` Identity
- If this is an mvc route, the mvc controller creates an instance
- Any actions are executed

This of course makes no sense at all!

So the questions are as follows

1. Is my inference of the order of things in the pipeline correct?
2. How can I control it to work properly? Why would this have worked on other projects but be causing problems here? Am I wiring something up in the wrong order?

Please don't suggest that I create an `IdentityProvider` to late-resolve `IIdentity`. I understand how I can fix the issue, what I don't understand is why this is happening to begin with and how to control the pipeline order of things.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using same IoC configuration for both ASP MVC and Web API? As far as know, both of them use different factories to create controllers

Comment: @tutok see the last two lines of my first code block

Comment: have you tried to get ICurrentUser from a WebApi with a delay (supposed 500ms) and observe the difference (if any)?

Comment: @ymz what do you mean? Tried that to do *what*?

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code just a little, since I don't have `NullIdentity()` and your `CurrentUserProvider` wasn't compiling here.

I'm installed these packages:

- Autofac
- Autofac.Owin
- Autofac.Owin
- Autofac.Mvc5
- Autofac.Mvc5.Owin
- Autofac.WebApi2
- Autofac.WebApi2.Owin

My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        configureIoC(app);
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    void configureIoC(IAppBuilder app) {

        var b = new ContainerBuilder();
        //...
        b.RegisterType<CurrentUserProvider>().As <ICurrentUser>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        b.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        b.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        var x = new ApplicationDbContext();
        b.Register<ApplicationDbContext>(c => x).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.Register<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(c => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(x)).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var container = b.Build();

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    }

}
```

Your `ICurrentUser` stuff:

```
public interface ICurrentUser
{
    Task <ApplicationUser> Get();
}

public class CurrentUserProvider : ICurrentUser
{

    private  ApplicationUserManager users;
    private  IIdentity currentLogin;

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> Get()
    {
        return await users.FindByNameAsync(currentLogin.GetUserId());
    }

    public CurrentUserProvider(ApplicationUserManager users, IIdentity currentLogin)
    {
        this.users = users;
        this.currentLogin = currentLogin;
    }

}
```

Therefore Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

My `HomeController` which is quite simple:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private ICurrentUser current;

    public HomeController(ICurrentUser current)
    {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = current.Get();
        if (user  == null)
            throw new Exception("user is null");
        return View();
    }

}
```

...and finally a simple ApiController, which I access by typing **localhost/api/TestApi/5**:

```
public class TestApiController : ApiController
{

    private ICurrentUser current;

    public TestApiController(ICurrentUser current)
    {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        var user = current.Get();
        if (user == null)
            throw new Exception("user is null");
        return "";
    }

}
```

If I just start the project (without even logging in), I receive a GenericIdentity object to support IIdentity interface, look at this:

[image: Debugging]

And when I step in (F11) in the `Get()` method, the `IIdentity` is properly set with that `GenericIdentity`, because actually there is no one Logged in the application. That's why I think you don't actually need that NullableIdentity.

[image]

Try comparing your code with mine and fix yours so we can see if it works, then eventually you'll find out what was the **real cause** of the problem, rather than just fixing it (we developers like to know why something just got working).